# Mortgage Cash Calculator in R

Tags: r

I am trying to replicate the table output from http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=mortgage using R. I have the following code set up but am not sure what to do next?

```
mortgage_cash_flow_enginer <- function(loan_amt,loan_period,APR){
                loan_amt <- readline(prompt = "Loan Amount: ")
                loan_period <- readline(prompt = "Loan Peroid: ") 
                APR <- readline(prompt = "Annual Percentage Rate (%): ")


                pmt_numerator <- ((loan_amt)*((APR)/(100*12L)))
                morpmt_denomenator <- (1-((1+((APR)/(100*12L)))^((-1)*loan_period*12)))
                monthly_payment <- (pmt_numerator)/(pmt_denomenator)
                return(as.integer(monthly_payment))
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the problems with your code:

1. The classes are not properly set on the input objects
2. You didn't have an object called `pmt_denomenator` but you referenced it (it was called something else)

This code runs fine now:

```
mortgage_cash_flow_engineer <- function(){
  loan_amt <- as.numeric(readline(prompt = "Loan Amount: "))
  loan_period <- as.numeric(readline(prompt = "Loan Peroid: ") )
  APR <- as.numeric(readline(prompt = "Annual Percentage Rate (%): "))


  pmt_numerator <- ((loan_amt)*((APR)/(100*12)))
  pmt_denomenator <- (1-((1+((APR)/(100*12)))^((-1)*loan_period*12)))
  monthly_payment <- (pmt_numerator)/(pmt_denomenator)
  return(as.integer(monthly_payment))
}

mortgage_cash_flow_engineer()#200000,30,.0365
```

So, that fixes the programming bugs in your code, but I believe the formula you're using is still different. This is the [correct formula](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=mortgage&rawformassumption=%22FSelect%22%20-%3E%20%7B%7B%22FixedRateMortgage%22%7D%7D&rawformassumption=%7B%22F%22,%20%22FixedRateMortgage%22,%20%22MA%22%7D%20-%3E%22$200000%22&rawformassumption=%7B%22F%22,%20%22FixedRateMortgage%22,%20%22MP%22%7D%20-%3E%2230%20yr%22&rawformassumption=%7B%22F%22,%20%22FixedRateMortgage%22,%20%22APR%22%7D%20-%3E%223.65%20%25%22&rawformassumption=%7B%22FVarOpt%22%7D%20-%3E%20%7B%7B%22FixedRateMortgage%22,%20%22PTS%22%7D,%20%7B%22FixedRateMortgage%22,%20%22MA%22%7D%7D&rawformassumption=%7B%22C%22,%20%22mortgage%22%7D%20-%3E%20%7B%22MathWorld%22%7D&rawformassumption=%7B%22MC%22,%22%22%7D-%3E%7B%22Formula%22%7D).

Comment: Thanks for the help. I made the update to the formula as well works as needed.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone was looking for the updated formula and code (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Mortgage.html):

```
  mortgage_cash_flow_engineer <- function(){
  loan_amt <- as.numeric(readline(prompt = "Loan Amount ($): "))
  loan_period <- as.numeric(readline(prompt = "Loan Period (months): ") )
  APR <- (as.numeric(readline(prompt = "Annual Percentage Rate (%): "))/100)


  pmt_numerator <- ((loan_amt*(APR/12))*((1+(APR/12))^loan_period))
  pmt_denomenator <- ((1+(APR/12))^loan_period)-1
  monthly_payment <- (pmt_numerator)/(pmt_denomenator)
  return(as.numeric(monthly_payment))
}

mortgage_cash_flow_engineer()
```